# What is the second 'auth' argument in the return signature of authentication.BaseAuthentication.authenticate?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#example

"The method should return a two-tuple of (user, auth) if authentication succeeds..."

```
return (user, None)
```

What exactly is that second 'auth' argument? In all the examples I've seen it's always None. Is there any scenario where it would be something else?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [source](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py%20Source).

I think the auth argument is used by authentication methods using access_tokens.

Let's take a look at one example.

```
class TokenAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    """
    Simple token based authentication.

    Clients should authenticate by passing the token key in the "Authorization"
    HTTP header, prepended with the string "Token ".  For example:

        Authorization: Token 401f7ac837da42b97f613d789819ff93537bee6a
    """

    model = Token
    """
    A custom token model may be used, but must have the following properties.

    * key -- The string identifying the token
    * user -- The user to which the token belongs
    """

    def authenticate(self, request):
        auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()

        if not auth or auth[0].lower() != b'token':
            return None

        if len(auth) == 1:
            msg = 'Invalid token header. No credentials provided.'
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
        elif len(auth) > 2:
            msg = 'Invalid token header. Token string should not contain spaces.'
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        return self.authenticate_credentials(auth[1])

    def authenticate_credentials(self, key):
        try:
            token = self.model.objects.get(key=key)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid token')

        if not token.user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('User inactive or deleted')

        return (token.user, token)

    def authenticate_header(self, request):
        return 'Token'
```

You'll see that authenticate() calls authenticate_credentials() which returns the user object and the access token.

Answer (score 0):

In rest_framework, the `auth` value returned by `authenticate` gets assigned to `request.auth`.

I think it's meant to hold arbitrary metadata about the authentication process, for later use by the view or permission classes. The semantics of this metadata are left unspecified, and up to the implementor.

An example use can be seen in [Django OAuth Toolkit's TokenHasScope](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/permissions.html#tokenhasscope) permission class. Here, the `auth` object [holds the token scope](https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/fe7b08673f377878b6e9e68213be48658990ff46/oauth2_provider/contrib/rest_framework/permissions.py#L14-L27).

In `rest_framework` itself, I don't believe `auth` is actively used. Although a value is returned from TokenAuthentication, it appears the value is never read.